# Which is the right Youtube Api URL to rate a video with an authenticated user?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm doing a Android App and I've done that an user can authenticate with OAuth 2.0 in a Youtube account. But when I try to rate a video which is the right URL to rate it.

I send a POST request with this string:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/sxbHyiwYDiw/ratings?value=like&key=my_access_token&v=2

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/video_id/ratings?value=like_or_dislike&key=my_access_token&v=2

It return this response: "`Response contains no content type`"

Edit:

I use this link to check it: http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

I can do this action sending this POST URL: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/sxbHyiwYDiw/ratings"

Adding this headers

```
  httppost.setHeader("POST", "/feeds/api/videos/sxbHyiwYDiw/ratings");
  httppost.setHeader("GData-Version", "2");
  httppost.setHeader("X-GData-Key", "key=*********");
  httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "AuthSub token=" + getAccessToken());
  httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml");
```

...and adding a xml body

You can check it in the first link: Youtube Demo.